# Get extension_attributes in Plugin

Tags: magento2, rest-api, plugin, extension-attributes

In my API response (all orders) I get this extension_attributes

```
"extension_attributes": {
    "my_attributes": {
        "order_id": null,
        "company_id": 1,
        "company_name": "TestCompany 1"
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use / get these values in an `afterGetList` Plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure your plugin is executed last. Give him lowest priority possible. Then try:

```
$order->getExtensionAttributes()->...
```